# UK Spouse Visa - Both partners working overseas

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, uk-visa, family

I am married to a British citizen. My spouse moved to my home country (non-EU) after our marriage. I have been employed in my country for the last 10 years, and my spouse has also established employment here for over one year.

My question is, if at some point in the future we make a decision to move to the UK, is it possible for us to make the spouse visa application while both of us are still working outside UK? Our combined income exceeds the 18,600 pounds threshold comfortably. Our intention would be to quit our jobs once we receive the visa approval and make the move together. Financially, we do not have any issues, prior to marriage my spouse had a stable job/income in the UK. We just want to avoid the process of the spouse having to move first to the UK, establishing work again for 6 months and spending a long time apart.

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer, Yes. I will link to the duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relocating to the UK with spouse](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13116/relocating-to-the-uk-with-spouse)